# Unable to open WebSocket in ES5 Slack API

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5, slack-api

Hello I was trying to create a slack bot of mine. I was successful when I was working with plain JavaScript, but I decided to switch to ES5 for certain reasons. Though the client starts the rtm but is unable to authenticate using the websockets. I am adding my files below to demonstrate my code. Won't hesitate to upvote your answer, please help! Thanks! :)

> Javascript

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

const service = require('../server/service');
const http = require('http');
const slackClient = require('../server/slackClient');
const server = http.createServer(service);

const slackToken = '-----SlackTokenHere----';
const slackLogLevel = 'verbose';
const rtm = slackClient.init(slackToken, slackLogLevel, witClient);
rtm.start();
slackClient.addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, () => server.listen(3000));

server.on('listening', function() {
  console.log(`Slackster is listening on ${server.address().port} in ${service.get('env')} mode.`);
});
```

**slackClient.js**

```
'use strict';

const RtmClient = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;
const CLIENT_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').CLIENT_EVENTS;
const RTM_EVENTS = require('@slack/client').RTM_EVENTS;
let rtm = null
let nlp = null

function handleOnAuthenticated(rtmStartData) {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${rtmStartData.self.name} of team ${rtmStartData.team.name}, but not yet connected to a channel`);
}

function handleOnMessage(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

function addAuthenticatedHandler(rtm, handler) {
  rtm.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM.AUTHENTICATED, handler);
}

module.exports.init = function slackClient(token, logLevel, nlpClient) {
  rtm = new RtmClient(token, {logLevel: logLevel});
  nlp = nlpClient;
  rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, handleOnMessage);
  return rtm;
}

module.exports.addAuthenticatedHandler = addAuthenticatedHandler;
```

> ES5

**index.js**

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
const server = http.createServer(express);

import slackClient from './Messenger_Clients/slackClient';


const slackToken = '------YourSlackToken------';
const slackLogLevel = 'verbose';
slackClient.init(slackToken, slackLogLevel, null);
slackClient.addAuthenticatedHandler(() => server.listen(3000));
server.on('listening', function() {
    console.log(`Slackster is listening on ${server.address().port} in ${service.get('env')} mode.`);
});
```

**slackClient.js**

```
import { RtmClient } from '@slack/client';
import { CLIENT_EVENTS } from '@slack/client';
import { RTM_EVENTS } from '@slack/client';

class slackClient {
    static init(token, logLevel, null) {
        this.rtm = new RtmClient(token, {logLevel: logLevel});
        this.nlp = nlpClient;
        this.rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, this.handleOnMessage);
        this.rtm.start();
    }
    static addAuthenticatedHandler(handler) {
        this.rtm.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.RTM_AUTHENTICATED, handler);
    }
    handleOnMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

module.exports = slackClient;
```

Comment: "but is unable to authenticate using the websockets" <-- what does that mean? Do you get some sort of error? If so, what is the error? If not, what happens that indicates there's a problem?

Comment: When you start a slack client it visits a url at https://slack.com/api/rtm, then it tries to authenticate you via WebSockets.

Comment: I know how the Slack API works. I'm asking what issue you're running into.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the Slack API. I guess I have an error in importing syntax in slackClient.js but I am unable to find where it is.

Comment: How do you expect people to help if you won't tell us what the issue is?

Comment: i just described the issue my friend. I said I have a problem in the syntax most probably, as the code runs in JS but not in ES5

Comment: Fine. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks! You could have helped, if you could just have a quick go through my code syntax if possible? Please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150269/discussion-between-trishant-pahwa-and-smarx).